# Why do I get a CORS error on API Gateway GET request when the OPTIONS request has statusCode 200?

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch, aws-api-gateway, requestjs

I am trying to make an GET HTTP request to a AWS API Gateway endpoint connected to a lambda function.

The endpoint and lambda function work as usual when tested with postman which is logical since postman doesn't use CORS.

However, when testing on firefox on chrome, I get the following error :

Firefox:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [*url*] (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Chrome:

> Access to fetch at [*url*] from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

But, if I look at the response of the CORS Preflight request, I see that "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is present:

> HTTP/2.0 200 OK
>   date: Tue, 12 Mar 2019 15:22:57 GMT
>   content-type: application/json
>   content-length: 0
>   x-amzn-requestid: [x-amzn-requestid]
>   **access-control-allow-origin: ***
>   access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token
>   x-amz-apigw-id: [x-amz-apigw-id]
>   access-control-allow-methods: GET,OPTIONS
>   X-Firefox-Spdy: h2

I tried using both the [fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch) and [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) packages for my request, with the following code (I wrapped the *request* call in a Promise, to use an async-await flow like the *fetch* call):

```
const getPolicy = (baseUrl, bucketNameTranscribe, fileName, apiKey) => (
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({
             url: `${baseUrl}?bucketName=${bucketNameTranscribe}&key=${fileName}`,
             method: "GET",
             headers: {
                 "x-api-key": apiKey
             }
        }, ((error, response) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                resolve(JSON.parse(response.body));
            } else {
                reject(response);
            }
        });
    })
);

const upload = async() {
    const {
        policyUrl,
        bucketNameTranscribe,
        apiKey
    } = awsConfig;
    const fileName = `${Date.now()}.mp3`;
    const req = new Request(
        `${policyUrl}?bucketName=${bucketNameTranscribe}&key=${fileName}`,
         {       
             method: "GET",
             headers: new Headers({
                 "x-api-key": apiKey
             })
         }
    );

    try {
        const response1 = await fetch(req);
        console.log("fetch", response1);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("errorFetch", error);
    }

    try {
        const response2 = await getPolicy(policyUrl, bucketNameTranscribe, fileName, apiKey);
        console.log("request", response2);
    } catch (exp) {
        console.error("errorRequest", exp);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `content-type: application/json
content-length: 0` — Your OPTIONS response shouldn't say it is sending JSON if it is sending nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present **on the requested resource**.

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is missing from the **actual** resource, not the response to the preflight OPTIONS request.

It needs to be on *both*.

Comment: That was it, thank you very much ! I followed this [guide](https://enable-cors.org/server_awsapigateway.html), to enable CORS on the method and it worked.